# Regular expressions in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, boolean, logic, boolean-logic

Hi I'm new to javascript and I have the following function:

```
function checkform() {
    var theForm = document.getElementById('login_form');
    var regName = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/;
    var firstname = theForm.firstname.value;

    if (
        (firstname == "" || theForm.firstname.value.length > 30 ) &&
        (regName.test(firstName) == false)
    ) {
        alert("That is not a valid first name!");
        theForm.firstname.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

It works in the sense that it checks that the data is not empty and not greater than 30. My problem is that is currently allows the user to enter data that does not match my regex i.e. numerical data. I can not see any problems with the logic.

Thanks

Comment: Check the RegularExpression on `KeyPress` or `Blur` event and if doesnt match then clear the `textbox`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your conditional statement try doing this:

```
if ((firstname == "" || theForm.firstname.value.length > 30 ) || (regName.test(firstname) == false)) {
    // ...
}
```

I've changed the "&&" (and) operator to "||" (or), because you don't need to check against both conditions (empty or longer than 30 AND not matching regexp), but just any of them (empty or longer than 30 or not mathing regexp).

Comment: Precicely .. in fact it would pass if the string was 40 long and the regex was satisfied ... and if the form element length is set to 30 chars anyway he'd only need the empty string test || the regex test

Comment: Have tried this soloution and still allows the test data - '128'.

Comment: I've updated the code snippet with "firstname" instead of "firstName" (Javascript is case-sensitive language), try it now.

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
 var regName = /^[a-zA-Z ]{3,30}$/;
 if (!regName.test(firstName)){ //make an error
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="txtChar" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" 
       type="text" name="txtChar">

   function isNumberKey(evt)
   {
      var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
      if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) || event.value > 30)
         return false;

      return true;
   }
```